# g++: error: CreateProcess no such file or directory

Tags: c++, g++, mingw, c++11, createprocess

I get the following error:

```
g++: error: CreateProcess no such file or directory
```

whenever I try to compile a program. I have installed the MinGw 7.2 version at work on a windows machine and the problem does not occur, however after installing Windows SP3 on my home computer I get this error and I just can't figure it out since I have set all the environment variables properly. I even tried setting the path to `C:\MinGw\libexec\gcc\i686-mingw32\4.6.1` where cc1plus.exe and cc1.exe are located but still no luck.If i type this at the command line:

> _assoc .cpp=cpls
>
> _ftype cpls=g++ "%1" %*
>
> _program.cpp

it seemse to compile since I get compile time errors for the C++11 keywords which aren't recognized without the -std=c++0x switch. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have MinGW's 'w32api' package installed? If not, you need it.

Comment: To help you check whether this is a MinGW problem, or a problem with your files, have you tried compiling on another platform? The g++ error in the question is produced by g++ itself (so the problem is not that it can't find `cc1plus.exe` and friends). e.g. `g++ foo_bar_file_does_not_exist` produces a similar error for me (on a linux system with g++ on the path)

Comment: The files compile fine with the same version of MinGW http://nuwen.net/mingw.html on another windows machine so i don't see where the problem might be.I also have Ubuntu installed and i can compile fine.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error and I tried reinstalling MinGW, changing Path, etc

Finally, Removing the GCC_EXEC_PREFIX env variable made from the Environment variable for both User and System made it work!
And this was also the root cause of the reason why CMake said C compiler identification is unknown.
In my case I think it was because Qt ships with its own MinGW. That could be the reason for you too (ie, mingw already exists elsewhere)

Comment: I looked for that env variable but it wasn't defined. Anyway i solved the problem by defining the path to MinGW\bin first in the PATH env variable.(doesn't make sense but it worked)

Answer (score 0):

You're compiling a 32 bit binary and trying to run it on a 64 bit system.

Compile the binary for the 64 bit architecture and it should work fine :)

http://www.drangon.org/mingw/